# How to remove all permissions from a group in Django

Tags: django, permissions

In Django authentication permissions, how to remove all permissions granted to a group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are separate ways to do this.

- via `admin`

  - edit your group and simply remove all permissions
    [image]
- via `database`

  ```sql
  DELETE FROM auth_group_permissions WHERE group_id=<id>;
  ```
- via `shell`

  ```bash
  $ python manage.py shell
  ```

  ```py
  >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
  >>> group = Group.objects.get(id=<id>)
  >>> group.permissions.clear()
  ```

*Edit: `.clear()` makes more sense than `.all().delete()`, thx Ivan ;)*

Comment: Won't `.all().delete()` remove the related *permission objects*? So that would result in the fact that the permissions no longer exists, not the permissions to that group.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep, already corrected it as I saw the other answer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yep, thats how I ended up here.